# Missing 'debug' command from Play 2.0 installed from Typesafe

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, typesafe-stack

I installed play 2.0 from the typesafe stack.

However, when i try to run sbt debug run it gives me the error:

```
[error] Not a valid key: debug (similar: idea)
```

Any suggestions on how to run a debug server?

Answer (score 8):

In order to debug with the sbt command instead of the play command, you have the option to set the env. variable `SBT_OPTS` with the classical
`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999`

Source : https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr&fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/-RVlEh8S2F4

Comment: how can i set the  SBT_OPTS variable ??

Comment: Like any other `environment variable`, it depends on your OS.

Comment: @JulienLafont i set the SBT_OPTS , and when im echo $SBT_OPTS
this is what i get "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999
"
BUT i cant run the debug command

Comment: this does not work for CMD , although `
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999` displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite some time on this tonight. Hope my experience helps.

And as many of you I am encountering same issue that `debug` is not recognized under `sbt`. The easiest way of course is to follow the documentation. install the Play standalone and run the `play debug run` command, and then debug remote java application using the 9999 port.

but @Julienlafont 's solution did workout as well (I had the confusion at first as well). The key is to understand the whole process. Play web server is still served through port 9000. but port 9999 is opened as debug port to let IDE connect to , this is important.

I guess the reason why `debug` is not recognized is because it is not a sub command at all. it is indeed a couple of JVM arguments as @Julienlafont point out. so the what `play` command did is simply wrap the JVM argument for you. note once you enter the play console, the `debug` extension wont be recognized, because its essence is a couple of JVM arguments.

so go ahead set that JVM argument, once you see the hint , you are done with opening the debug port. run your server and finish the remaining part.